# SQL dynamic column name

Tags: sql, netezza

How do I declare a column name that changes?

I take some data from DB and I am interested in last 12 months, so I only take events that happend, let's say in '2016-07', '2016-06' and so on...

Then, I want my table to look like this:

```
event type | 2016-07 | 2016-06
-------------------------------
    A      |   12    |   13
    B      |   21    |   44
    C      |   98    |   12
```

How can I achieve this effect that the columns are named using previous YYYY-MM pattern, keeping in mind that the report with that query can be executed any time, so it would change.

Simplified query only for prev month:

```
select distinct 
    count(event),
    date_year_month,
    event_name 
from 
   data_base
where date_year_month = TO_CHAR(add_months(current_date, -1),'YYYY-MM')
group by event_name, date_year_month
```

Comment: your question seems completely confusing to me :) make some simplifications and add some more details.

Comment: just edited, hope it is clear now :)

Comment: Checkout Pivot ... you can make dynamic pivot that turns your result into thing you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an automated way of pivoting the year-month columns, and change the number of columns in the result dynamically based on the data.

However if you are looking for pivoting solution, you accomplish using table functions in netezza.

```
select event_name, year_month, event_count
from event_counts_groupby_year_month, table(inza.inza.nzlua('
local rows={}
function processRow(y2016m06, y2016m07)
    rows[1] = { 201606, y2016m06 }
    rows[2] = { 201607, y2016m07 }
    return rows
end

function getShape()
    columns={}
    columns[1] = { "year_month", integer }
    columns[2] = { "event_count", double }
    return columns
end',
y2016m06, y2016m07));
```

you could probably build a wrapper on this to dynamically generate the query based on the year month present in the table using shell script.